# Maven Failsafe: verify always returns exit code 0

Tags: java, maven-3, java-8, maven-failsafe-plugin

I'm having an exceptionally annoying issue with my integration tests, where the Maven failsafe plugin is returning an exit code of 0, regardless of the actual result of the tests:

eg, running 'mvn verify' shows:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 23.519s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Sep 16 13:12:55 BST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 53M/512M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.6:verify       (verify) on project [my.project]: There are test failures.
```

....

```
echo $?
0
```

failsafe config:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>integration-test</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>verify</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I've never seen this issue crop up before and it renders my CI stack worthless, as builds don't fail if the tests fail! The only difference between this and similar things i've done in the past is that i'm using java 8 here.

Comment: Is this actually a Failsafe-specific thing? Try running Maven in a directory without a project -- that causes a failure -- and see what that error code is.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problem - it looks like the stop-jetty execution from the maven jetty plugin was causing strange behaviour with exit codes. Removing the stop-jetty execution fixes the error (and my CI will kill Jetty anyway)